# SQL Server fetch with syntax error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using the following sample code with SQL Server, and it is returning a syntax error:

```
select id, user_id, cmd_id
from configs
order by user_id
offset 0 rows
fetch next 10 row only
```

How do I adjust the syntax?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Reading the documentation would have answered this question very quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is correct. Are you using SQL 2012+? The Offset/Fetch clause is not available in older versions.

If you are using an older version, try the following:

```
with cte as
(
  select id, user_id, cmd_id,
    row_number() over (order by user_id) as rn
  from configs
)
select id, user_id, cmd_id
from cte
where rn > 0 -- 0 is the offset
  and rn <= 10 + 0 -- 10 is the limit + 0 the offset
```